# Finding and inserting into table based on a string sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function in my code that generates a bunch of tables on an API call. It looks somewhat like this:

```
def create_tables():
  rows = connection.execute(sqlcmd)
  for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    # Do some work here
    t = Table(f"data_{i}", metadata, *columns)
  metadata.create_all()
```

I need another function where I iterate over the tables created in above function, then dump records in to each table from another API. Since, I'm not using declarative mapping or models in sqlalchmey, how do I identify these tables in my database and write data to specific table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [reflection system](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects)

```
meta.reflect(bind=someengine)
# now all located tables are present within the MetaData object’s 
# dictionary of tables
table1 = meta.tables['data_1']
table1.insert().values(...)
```